# How to display express validator errors in a div

Tags: node.js, ejs, express-validator

I'm using express validator to validate a form and I'm able to get the results however, I'm not sure how to display it into my EJS file.

```
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
           let error = errors.array().map(i => `${i.msg}`).join(' ');
           res.render('sell', { title: 'Sell', error: errors });
        }
```

ejs file

```
                    <% if (error != null) { %>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <%= error %>
                        </div>

                            <% } %>
```

This code only returns the errors on one line, I want it to display the errors in its own alert div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a for loop for errors like this

```
<% if (error !=null) { %>
    <% for (const err of error) { %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <%= err %>
      </div>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

and I would actually rename it to errors since it's plural

Comment: The errors are still on one line but in separate divs instead. So its displaying as `<div>error 1, error2</div><div>error 1, error2</div>` instead of `<div>error1</div><div>error2</div>`. I think the problem might be in my error handling but it feels like I've tried everything and it still won't work.

Comment: oh sorry edited the comment to change `error` to `err`, it was a typo, if you try it now it will work

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works, I've been trying to figure out this problem for days.

Comment: Btw, there's a missing closing tag for the loop, for future people who need this also.

Comment: @Chris fixed that, that's what happens when you write without an IDE